# MS Word crashes if document has a SP2013 managed metadata column - NEED Patch!

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, office, patching, hotfix

**Here's my scenario:**
I have a Content Type called "Work Plan" with managed metadata column called "Department". This content type has a Word Document Template and if I go to the Ribbon > New Document > Work Plan the document opens for a second and Word crashes.

**This is a documented problem:**
If a Word document has a managed metadata column AND the Document Information Panel (DIP) is open the application crashes.

Example:
http://sharepoint-for-real.blogspot.ca/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-document-information.html

**One solution** is to repair Office one-by-one.

However, we have 1300 computers so this is not feasible.

**My question is:** 
Is there a MS Office patch or hotfix that can be pushed out to update MS Office and fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Yikes.  So, in order to prevent crashes, you have to repair the installation of office?  Any idea what service or class might be corrupted or responsible for the crash?  This is something that may impact my organization and, not to put too fine a point on things, but we'll have your problem but an order of magnitude greater.

Comment: We just don't have the resources to go to each computer an update MS Office. A patch or hotfix would be the ideal.

Comment: To be honest, neither do we.  What version of Office are you all using?

Comment: MS Office 2010 & some on Office 2007. I still can't find a patch or fix. It's a huge problem in my design. The only alternative is for people to Upload a template and enter the metadata after upload - not ideal!!